# How to allow guest access to page while still using "middleware:('verified')" on Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5.8

I want the guest to access Home and Shop page and still verifies email when a user wants to register.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EnsureEmailIsVerified` middleware requires the user to be logged in to access any pages protected with it.

You can see this check in the [code for the middleware](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Middleware/EnsureEmailIsVerified.php)

```php
if (!$request->user() ||
    ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        !$request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
    // reject
}
```

If you want to allow guests to access the page, and still require users to be activated you will need to create a custom middleware.

```sh
php artisan make:middleware GuestOrActivated
```

Then, for the `handle` function:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail && !$request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
            : Redirect::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working. If I browse the website as a guest I have no problem. Even if I log in with an unverified user. BUT If I login as an unverified user and type /home in the address bar I still have access to /home. But that is exactly what I want to forbid! I don't want people who are not verified to browse the website. How can I do this? @atymic

Answer (score 1):

For that case I make new middleware, before redirect to email verify, I flush the session, so when user back to home, he will redirect to login again

```
class GuestOrActivated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
    {
        if ($request->user() && $request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail && !$request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            request()->session()->flush();
            return Redirect::route('verification.notice');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```